# How to select elements that aren't loaded yet in the HTML DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a tool-tip for some icons (over 1400+ png) that takes time to load into the DOM using JavaScript. The problem is that my code needs to select all the parent elements of the icons then covert them to array then do the styling and positioning but since the whole thing takes time to load my code ends up selecting nothing and returning an empty array. I tried to use `setInterval()` and it works but the tool-tip then takes more time to show up and it becomes really slow. I tired onload events but they don't work either... any workaround this problem is appreciated...

```js
let setUpToolTip = () => {
  let tooltip = " ";
  tooltipEmoji = document.querySelector('.Emoji-tooltip')
  toolTipElements = document.querySelectorAll('.Emoji')
  console.log(toolTipElements)
  const tooltipElemArray = Array.from(toolTipElements)
  let timer;

  let displayTooltip = (e, step) => {
    tooltip = step
    tooltipEmoji.innerHTML = tooltip
    tooltipEmoji.style.top = e.pageY + "px"
    tooltipEmoji.style.left = e.pageX + "px"
    fadeIN(tooltipEmoji)
  }

  let fadeOut = function(e) {
    let op = 1;
    if (!timer) {
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (op <= 0.1) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          timer = null
          e.style.opacity = 0;
          e.style.display = "none";
        }
        e.style.opacity = op;
        op -= op * 0.1
      }, 10)

    }
  }
  let fadeIN = function(e) {
    let op = 0.1;
    e.style.display = "block"
    var timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (op >= 1) {
        clearInterval(timer);

      }
      e.style.opacity = op;
      op += op * 0.1
    }, 10)
  }

  tooltipElemArray.forEach((e) => {
    const step = e.dataset.tooltip
    let timeout;
    e.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        displayTooltip(e, step)
      }, 400)
    });

    e.addEventListener("mouseleave", e => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      fadeOut(tooltipEmoji)
    })
  })
}


setUpToolTip();
```

Comment: The only thing you can do is put your code into the `window` object's `load` event handler. Then it will run as soon as all the DOM elements have completed loading their resources. You may want to verify that your images are as small of a file size as they can be and that your server is compressing content before sending.

Comment: Note that you can do styling and positioning in CSS before the elements ever load. There's little reason to do this in JavaScript...

Comment: Have you tried setting up each image with its tooltip when it (the image) loads? And is there a reason for doing the animations (fading etc) in JS rather than CSS?

Comment: @ScottMarcus tried that it didn't work .

Comment: @AHaworth: the reason i used javascript is because i need to use overflow in the parents , making the tool-tip with pure css locks it inside the child when the overflow is auto or hidden , wasted lot of time on it so i decide to just go with java script and it did the job done , as far as the icons are concerned their is over 1400 for i used java script to load them there's no way I'm going to manually set them up in html

Comment: There's no reason why setting up a handler for the `window.load` event wouldn't work for what you are describing. This is exactly why there is a `load` event. You'll need to explain what "didn't work" means.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setUpToolTip, false);
```

Try setup tooltips after DOM  loaded